# Opinions about windshield blimp

Tags: blimp, windshield

Hi everyone,

I'm looking to buy a zeppelin for the microphone, but usually used in big productions I can not pay. I've looked at alternatives and found this, someone has tried and can compare it with other professionals?

http://cgi.ebay.es/60cm-Blimp-Windscreen-Windjammer-Windshield-Fur-Cover-/140499923350?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item20b672b196#ht_5529wt_905

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

I think these are the ones being made in India. I have not used one myself but a guy I did some field recording with the other day had one and said t did the job well enough. Compared to a similar Rycote one I thought the plastic looked and felt quite brittle which would mean bits are more likely to snap on it. The guy said he also had to change the bands that came with it that hold the mic as they were not very good. You get what you pay for really and this will do the job but is not near the standards of a Rycote or even Rode wind shield. If you really have little money you can make your own windshield with very little trouble, they work well, the only downside is that if you turned up on a set with one you may receive a few funny looks. Here is an example of one method [link text](http://www.joelandkaren.com/mic-zeppelin/) This one seems fine but I would also recommend using old speaker cover fabric around the cage as this is essentially the same stuff used on the Rycote zeplins and will help with wind reduction whilst not effecting your recordings quality.

Comment: thanks Lenny, but I think it will be better a mediocre product (like India windshield) than do it myself.

Answer (score 3):

Keep an eye on ebay and other local secondhand markets - two of the four rycotes I own I bought secondhand.... Remember Rycotes have been around for a long time so there are perfectly functional old models around - one of mine would be well over 20 years old, the suspension and cage are in perfect condition, will replace the fluffy sometime soon but still....

Comment: @timeprebble have you ever had to replace the rubber filler strips on yours?  I just had one dry out and start creaking.  Only 10 years old

Answer (score 2):

@Alvar, the best commercially-available low-cost zeppelin that I've found is the Røde Blimp. The one you linked to looks an awful lot like a Sennheiser MZW windscreen, which currently retails online for US$360. I still prefer the modularity, flexibility, and performance of Rycote, as most on this board probably do also, but really, for the price the Røde Blimp can do the job in many circumstances.

I am also aware of one or two Indian retailers on eBay who sell stuff on the cheap, sometimes major brands, sometimes their own, of pretty mixed quality...popular with the DV and no-budget/guerilla filmmaking scene, though.

As @Lenny said, if you have more time than money, you can make your own. Tutorials abound online! (I've always been an admirer of the DIY windscreens of nature recordists who use dual NT1a's for nature ambiences!)

Comment: Thanks NoiseJockey, exactly! the problem of Rode is that the microphones do not enter if they are longer than NTG and I think there isn't an extension module as Rycote. But Rycote is too expensive. I dn't know what will do.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a Rycote Softie, they still give a decent sound and are robust?

http://www.rycote.com/products/softie_kit/